# Check if the file size greater than 1MB using IF condition

Tags: linux, size

By using `ls -lh` we can get the file size.

Is there any way I can check if the file size is greater than 1MB to then print a message like below? I may have files with different sizes like 100mb, 1gb, 10gb, 100kb.

```
if [ $FileSize > 1MB ];
then
    echo "File size is grater than 1MB"
fi
```

Is there a way I can check the file size using an `if` statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `find` on a specific file at `$filepath`:

```
if [ -n "$(find "$filepath" -prune -size +1000000c)" ]; then
    printf '%s is strictly larger than 1 MB\n' "$filepath"
fi
```

This uses `find` to query the specific file at `$filepath` for its size.  If the size is greater than 1000000 bytes, `find` will print the pathname of the file, otherwise it will generate nothing.  The `-n` test is true if the string has non-zero length, which in this case means that `find` outputted something, which in turns means that the file is larger than 1 MB.

You didn't ask about this: Finding all regular files that are larger than 1 MB under some `$dirpath` and printing a short message for each:

```
find "$dirpath" -type f -size +1000000c \
    -exec printf '%s is larger than 1 MB\n' {} +
```

These pieces of code ought be to portable to any Unix.

---

Note also that using `<` or `>` in a test will test whether the two involved strings sort in a particular way lexicographically.  These operators do not do numeric comparisons.  For that, use `-lt` ("less than"), `-le` ("less than or equal to"), `-gt` ("greater than"), or `-ge` ("greater than or equal to"), `-eq` ("equal to"), or `-ne` ("not equal to").  These operators do integer comparisons.

Comment: Do we need to provide "+1000000c" -- "c" along with bytes ?

Comment: @Ravi That is how you say 1 MB with standard `find`. GNU `find` may well understand `-size +1M`, as would `find` on e.g. macOS (but `1M` actually means 1 MiB with these implementations, i.e. units of powers of 2 bytes rather than of powers of 10 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query one single file at a time, `stat` is a general-purpose tool for querying various attributes of a particular file, including size among many others.

```
FileName="foo"
FSize=1048576
if [ $(stat -f %z "$FileName") -gt $FSize ]; then
    printf "File %s is larger than %d bytes.\n" "$FileName" $FSize
fi
```

If what you're really looking for is a way to query a large number of files, and pull out the names of only those files which are over a certain size, then `find` may be what you want.

Given a group of files located in DIRECTORY, this will find those files larger than FSize bytes:

```
DIRECTORY="/path/to/your/files"
FSize="1M"
find $DIRECTORY -type f -size +$FSize
```

Comment: What is `stat -f %z`? on my system it is `stat -c %s` for filesize in bytes